# clang++ direct string serialization to binary file just works?

Tags: c++, string, serialization, clang++

I inocently created structure like this:

```
struct data{
    std::string name;
    std::string surname;
};
```

Then to save objects of this type in file I used:

```
data d;
ifstream bin("filename", ios::binary);
bin.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&d), sizeof(data));
```

I compiled it with clang on macOS Sierra. Because this is my CS assignment and one of requirements is building in CodeBlocks on Windows and there program doesn't serialize properly. I started looking why and found out that I can't write data this way and my code is just wrong.

The my question is: **why it works in clang properly, when clearly it shoudn't?**

EDIT:
By working correctly I mean that my program writes and reads proper structures without losing data in strings.

Comment: What does "why it works in clang properly" mean? Does it compile? run? produce correct results when you read it back?

Comment: How long are `d`'s strings? Try making them long. Then your code might stop "working".

Comment: What does "serialize properly" mean? What kind of expectations do you have on your code (other than producing meaningless garbage)? Did you test it with long strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is not allowed in C++, but it might work on some platforms.  Specifically, it might work on platforms which implement the "new" C++11 ABI for std::string, which implements the "small string optimization" whereby short strings (under, say, 31 characters) are stored directly inside the object, rather than separately allocated on the heap.

If you put long strings like 50+ characters into your data before serializing, it will probably start failing.

Comment: IIRC, even some implementations using SSO won't work because they still use a pointer internally.

Comment: There's neither a "new C++11 ABI", nor an "ABI that implements SSO" part of *any* standard.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I didn't use the word "standard" and neither did OP.  Not sure what you're on about.

Comment: When you say "the", that implies that there's somehow only one, and that there is in fact any, and I'm disputing both of those.